# How to hide "edit with elementor" button from top adminbar?

Tags: wordpress, hide, elementor

I need to "edit with elementor" button, without deleting plugin, from adminbar in wordpress.

I have tried next code:

```
function hide_elementor_edit_link_from_admin_bar($wp_admin_bar) {
    if (is_admin_bar_showing()) {
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('edit-with-elementor');
    }
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'hide_elementor_edit_link_from_admin_bar', 999);
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved, -> Elementor have their own settings for this, just need to uncheck box in Elementor->Role Manager.